# Зависает приложение при Insert в БД

Tags: java, mysql

Выполняю учебный проект, в котором нужно создать удаленное файловое хранилище, файлы нужно хранить в БД, я использую MySQL. На данном этапе столкнулся с такой проблемой что при загрузке совсем небольших файлов проблемы нет, но при загрузке чего-то побольше, например мр3, приложение зависает примерно в одном и том же месте (-+8192байт).

```
public void sendToServer() throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    System.out.println("я тут");
    String extention = "";
    int i = String.valueOf(path1).lastIndexOf('.');
    if (i > 0) {
        extention = String.valueOf(path1).substring(i + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(extention);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(String.valueOf(path1)));
    System.out.println("размер файла " + bis.available());
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(Client.socket.getOutputStream());//при повторной отправке сокет закрыт

    byte[] byteArray = new byte[8192];
    int in;
    while ((in = bis.read(byteArray)) != -1) {
        bos.write(byteArray, 0, in);
        String insert = "INSERT INTO " + Configs.dbName + "." + Const.USER_TABLE_FILES +
                "(" + files_name + "," + files_data + ")" +
                "VALUES(?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = DatabaseHandler.getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, String.valueOf(path1.getFileName()));
        preparedStatement.setBytes(2, byteArray);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(bis.available());

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась удалением строки с  `bos.write(byteArray, 0, in);`